# ¿Por qué no compila?

Tags: c++, punteros

Estoy aprendiendo a usar punteros pero el programa no compila. ¿Por qué?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void par_impar (int, int*);

int main (){
    int numero, *dir_num; //dir_num -> direccion del num

    cout << "Digite un num ";
    cin >> numero;

    dir_num = &numero;

    cout << "Resultado: " << par_impar(numero, *dir_num) << endl;
}

void par_impar (numero, *dir_num){
    if (*dir_num%2==0){
        cout << "El numero: " << *dir_num << " es par" << endl;
        cout << "Posicion: " << dir_num << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "El numero: "<< *dir_num << " es impar" << endl;
        cout << "Posicion: "<< dir_num << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: No es necesario que nos compartas la teoría. Solo deja el código y dinos cuál es tu pregunta/problema. También explícanos brevemente qué intentas hacer o qué debería hacer el código.

Comment: @Mateo Si, puse la teoria porque no me dejaba publicar porque decia que era mucho codigo. Lo que intento hacer es que me diga si el numero es par o impar implementando punteros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes 3 errores principales:

En la línea:

```
cout << "Resultado: " << par_impar(numero, *dir_num) << endl;
```

Estás pasando 2 enteros. Porque con el asterisco `*` le dices al puntero que se desreferencie (lea el valor en la posición de memoria que apunta).

Debes pasarlo con el nombre de la variable a secas, así:

```
cout << "Resultado: " << par_impar(numero, dir_num) << endl;
```

Supongo que te pudo haber confundido la forma en que declaraste el puntero:

```
int numero, *dir_num;
```

Debes tener en cuenta que el nombre de la variable es `dir_num` solamente.

El asterisco cuando estás declarando la variable significa que tiene que ser un puntero (de tipo `int*` en tu caso). La principal diferencia es que cuando declaras/defines debes indicar el tipo de la variable (`int` en tu caso) y cuando lo desreferencias no escribes el tipo.

Otro problema que tienes en la misma línea es que el operador `<<` de `cout` espera que le pases un valor, pero la función `par_impar` es de tipo `void`, no devuelve nada.

Por lo que esa línea la puedes dividir en 2 y te quedaría así:

```
cout << "Resultado:\n";
par_impar(numero, dir_num);
```

---

El segundo error está en la definición de la función `par_impar`.

```
void par_impar (numero, *dir_num)
```

Una función se declara/define incluyendo:

- Tipo de retorno (`void` en este caso)
- Nombre (`par_impar`en este caso)
- Paréntesis
- Parámetros con su tipo dentro de los paréntesis.

La diferencia entre declarar y definir es que al declarar no indicas contenido o cuerpo, mientras que al definir sí. Opcionalmente, al declarar puedes omitir el nombre de los parámetros.

Declaración:
void par_impar(int numero, int* dir_num);

Definición (corrigiendo el problema):

```
void par_impar (int numero, int* dir_num)
{
    if (*dir_num%2==0){
        cout << "El numero: " << *dir_num << " es par" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "El numero: "<< *dir_num << " es impar" << endl;
    }
    cout << "Dirección de memoria: " << dir_num << endl;
}
```

---

Por si a caso, quiero mencionar que `dir_num` aunque su nombre signifique `dirección del número`, es una variable (mas específicamente un puntero porque guarda una dirección de memoria). La dirección del número la traes con el operador `&` y la guardas en el puntero en la línea `dir_num = &numero;`.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu pregunta es el porqué no te compila, pues el problema es que estás dereferenciando al puntero *dir_num* cuando lo pasas como argumento a la función *par_impar*, pero esa función toma un puntero como argumento, por lo tanto no tienes que dereferenciar al puntero, es decir, debes llamar a la función así ***par_impar(numero, dir_num)*** no ***par_impar(numero,*** ****dir_num)***, el resto está bien, sin embargo debes indicar el tipo de dato de los parámetros de las funciones tanto en su declaración como en la implementación, ya que eso podría provocar errores, además de ser una nomenclatura obsoleta.